# windows powershell ssh asks how would you like to open file

Tags: ssh, powershell, shell

No idea whats going on but ssh on powershell gives me the following  [image]

When I choose an option it just says could not open ssh because not supported file type.
Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What command exactly are you entering for ssh? What is the result of `where ssh.exe`?

Comment: @harrymc  ssh user01@training.uofa.c3.ca  
actually  I think it is just because  I didn't put ssh.exe didn't know you needed to do that in shell

Comment: `ssh.exe` is supposed to be in the folder `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` and this folder is supposed to be in the PATH, if you have properly enabled this feature in Windows.